# how to convert a double array to character string

Tags: string, matlab

hello i have entered some text and convert it to the binary values.these binary values get stored in a array of data type double. Now i want to get the char array from that array containing binary values.

```
text2='hello how are u';
text3=double(text2);
nValues = numel(text3);
B=8;
bit_stream = zeros(1,nValues*B);
% eight bit for binary representation of each character.
for iBit = 1:B                    %# Loop over the bits
bit_stream(iBit:B:end) = bitget(text3,B-iBit+1);  %# Get the bit values
end
bitstream=bit_stream;
```

how to perform vice-versa..

Comment: not sure if thats what you are looking for but did you try: `num2str()`?

Answer (score 0):

```
text2_recovered = char( 2.^(7:-1:0) * reshape(bit_stream, 8, []) );
```

Explanation:

1. Arrange bits in groups of 8 (`reshape(...,8,[])`);
2. Convert each group to a byte value (`2.^(7:-1:0)*...`) ;
3. Convert those bytes to characters (`char`).

Comment: thanks alot sir for your answer. Please answer another question.

Comment: In the second line of above given code, i am converting string to double. and how can i  get back text2 from text3. i have tried num2str and sprintf but these two didn't work.

Comment: @user3671724 `char(text3)`

Comment: sir now my text containing more than one line. Char(text3) did not worked for that.

Comment: @user3671724 Well, I'm afraid that's way out of the original question

Comment: sorry sir, i will explain it in detail with the code in another question.

Comment: @user3671724 My point is: that should be a new question. Your original posting to this question didn't say any of that